Removing option to add files/folders in explorer in vscode extension
I'm developing a vscode extension that has a custom fileSystemProvider (memfs), to represent a tree of assets from a remote system.
I want to remove the option/buttons to create new files/folders in the vscode Explorer, but cannot find any way to do so. Do you have any ideas?
Closest I'm getting is events, but this happens after the fact that the button is pressed, so it's not optimal.
vscode.workspace.onWillCreateFiles((e: vscode.FileWillCreateEvent)
